# Missing third party java package com.mattwelsh.framework.gui.tree

Tags: java, checkbox, jar, tree, package

So, after over a year of lurking at Stackoverflow, I've finally found a question that I cannot find an answer to either here or elsewhere.

I've been trying to modify some "old" Java code work (several years at least, egad!), while trying to fix an issue one of our customers is having.  Part of the code I fixed imports classes from a third party package that it seems someone forgot to put in our version control, and now I can't find the required package anywhere.  The package I am looking for would contain the classes:

```
com.mattwelsh.framework.gui.tree.CheckTree
com.mattwelsh.framework.gui.tree.CheckableTreeCellRenderer
com.mattwelsh.framework.gui.tree.CheckListener
com.mattwelsh.framework.gui.tree.CheckEvent
com.mattwelsh.framework.gui.tree.Checkable
```

I've already done 20+ Google searches over several days, and searched at findjar.com and the Maven Central Repository.  All these searches came up empty.  The only info that I have come up with is that Matt Welsh is a former Harvard professor in Computer Science who now works for Google.

My last hope is that someone here either knows a location where the jar (or code) for the package is available, or actually has a copy and can arraign to get it to me somehow.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Edit: BTW, I'm pretty sure this set of classes relates to a tree widget with checkboxes at each node.  I've seen several similar implementations, so I might be able to just replace the missing code with one of those.  Not ideal, necessarily, but doable in a pinch (which I seem to be in).

Comment: you can try decompiling the class files.

Comment: @happymeal There is no classfile available to decompile.

Comment: @happymeal did I overread it? He said that he don't find the classes? `"The package I am looking for would contain the classes"` Or what you mean?

Comment: I can't understand how you run the code without the jar.  Is this correct?  Even if so, can you reconstruct what you can of the interface from declarations and calls?  This could help.  I don't mean necessarily to reconstruct the source, but to find the package (or author?).

Comment: You know what the Name of the Project is what your searching or libaray??

Comment: If your customers are having a problem with the application, surely it is deployed somewhere with the mattwelsh jar included? Find out where it is running and fetch the jar from there.

Comment: Well, since I haven't been able to find the jar, either here or on the customer's system, I guess that's a pretty strong indication that the original developer had the source code.  I suppose I could try to decompile the code and see if that yields usable (or near usable) code, but then I've never had much luck decompiling code.  At this point I'd be satisfied with either source code or a jar.

Comment: @JackM Yea cool? I could try to find it if you could answer my question :)

Comment: You could use Maven and look at the [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/) for it.

Comment: @DLJ Yeah, I did try the Maven repository already (as mentioned in the question), but found nothing.